# How to return org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity includes data and files

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have restful spring controller with method getUser, I want this method to return user data: name, age, city, etc. and user images.

How can I return java object and files in one response?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity getUser(@RequestBody UserRequest req) 
    {
        User user=userProfileService.getUserProfileByEmail(req.getEmail());
        Resource resourceImg1 = new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "D:/images/userImg1.jpg");
        Resource resourceImg2 = new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "D:/images/userImg2.jpg");
        List<Resource> resourcesList = new ArrayList<Resource>();
        resourcesList.add(resourceImg1);
        resourcesList.add(resourceImg2);
        return new ResponseEntity(user, resourcesList, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I want to return the images and the user

Comment: Some options in : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data

Answer (score 2):

Your response body needs to be a single object. Your best bet is to create an object like

```
public class UserWithResources() {
    private User user;
    private List<Resources> resources;
    ...etc
}
```

then return the UserWithResources in your response

Answer (score 1):

You can use  map to wrap the data,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity getUser(@RequestBody UserRequest req) 
    {
        User user=userProfileService.getUserProfileByEmail(req.getEmail());
        Resource resourceImg1 = new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "D:/images/userImg1.jpg");
        Resource resourceImg2 = new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "D:/images/userImg2.jpg");
        List<Resource> resourcesList = new ArrayList<Resource>();
        resourcesList.add(resourceImg1);
        resourcesList.add(resourceImg2);
        Map<String,Object> dataMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        dataMap.put("user",user);
        dataMap.put("resourcesList",resourcesList);
        return new ResponseEntity(dataMap,new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Or can have a pojo as well